# Using SQL Server Management Studio, Why does SQL Server not retrieve existing values?

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016

I use SQL Server Management Studio with SQL Server 2016.
When I run this SQL statement, it doesn't return any values, even though the record is already there. Could you help please? What is the problem?

My query:

```
select *  
from device_os  
where name = '4.2 (Jelly Bean)'
```

This is the script for the table creation:

```
   USE [my_database]
    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[device_os]    Script Date: 08-Nov-17 3:49:11 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[device_os](
        [id] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_device_os] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ON 

    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (114, N'4.4.2')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (115, N'2.3.64.14.14.1')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (116, N'6.1.5')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (117, N'4.0.0')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (118, N'4.4.2 KOT49H.H1')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (119, N'unknown')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (120, N'CrunKeD! Galaxy Ace Ventura')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (121, N'7.0.5')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (122, N'7.0.6')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (123, N'6.1.6')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (124, N'4.4.2 (0Din Edition)')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (132, N'7.1.1')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (133, N'OS')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (134, N'4.2  (Jelly Bean)')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (135, N'5.0.0.1036')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (136, N'7.1.0.285')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (137, N'6.0.0.756')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (138, N'ICS Powered By PMP Engine')
    INSERT [dbo].[device_os] ([id], [name]) VALUES (139, N'6.0.0.668')

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[device_os] OFF
```

Screenshots for the problem :

`select *` without condition and the record is there 'highlighted in yellow'

[image]

When I add a condition on the value '4.2 (Jelly Bean)' no result there

[image]

Comment: what's with the `n)'` at the end?

Comment: Are there embedded spaces around the text in the record? Try using like instead. `Where name like '%4.2 (Jelly Bean)%'` and see what you get.

Comment: Hi WEI_DBA,
I tried like but the result is the same.

Comment: i bet there isn't a space between the 2 and (

Comment: Try to cast `name` as VARBINARY to see HEXA value

Comment: There's nothing wrong with SQL Server. Without your table's schema and data, it's impossible to tell what's wrong with the query. Post a *reproducible* script that creates the table, inserts the data, executes a SELECT statement that shows the problem. If you *can't* it means that your table doesn't contain the strings you think. Perhaps there are extra spaces, newlines or invisible characters

Comment: You can also check the length of name, '4.2 (Jelly Bean)' must contain 16 car.

Comment: kindly, check the creation script in the question @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @AbdollahSobhy is the `name` column only 1 character long? Thats what `varchar` means without a length.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is the creation script of the table: -

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[device_os](
 [id] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_device_os] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: Anyway, no repro with a `varchar(20)` column. Post the INSERT statements you used, eg `insert intodevice_os (name) values ('4.2 (Jelly Bean)')` . I bet you'll *not* be able to reproduce the problem. Did you load those values from a flat file perhaps?

Comment: Actually, it is setup data in my company from long time ago and I don't know how it was inserted. I have to manage the current data as is.

Comment: Then you have to find out what the data actually contains. WHERE isn't broken. People can't help you if they can't reproduce the problem. You can script the table's contents and post part of it here if you go to the database's context menu and select `Tasks > Generate Scripts`. Select only the table and in the next screen, click on `Advanced` and in the `Types of data to scrip` select `Schema and Data`

Comment: hi @PanagiotisKanavos I edited the question and added the script in the way you recommended. Any help please..

Comment: @AbdollahSobhy there are two spaces between `4.2` and `(Jelly Bean)`. This isn't apparent in the screenshot. It's more obvious now because SO uses a large fixed-width font for code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I take the value from the table as copy paste.. I didn't type it manually. I did the following: - 
1- Run (SELECT *) query.
2- Take the value "4.2  (Jelly Bean)" as copy paste from the (select *) query. 3- Put it in the where condition of the second query. 
The result is the same.  No data returned  :(

Answer (score 1):

The query at the top of your post should work:

```
select * 
from device_os where 
[name] = '4.2 (Jelly Bean)'
```

If it doesn't, you may have leading spaces. Note, trailing spaces usually doesn't matter for equality operators. Leading spaces do. If you think you may have them, try:

```
select * 
from device_os 
where ltrim([name]) = '4.2 (Jelly Bean)'
```

The only other thing it could be is you think you have a space in the name but you don't. Use this to see:

```
select * 
from device_os 
where ltrim([name]) = '4.2(Jelly Bean)' --space removed from between 2 and (
```

[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://rextester.com/KTJM46795)

Comment: Hi scsimon, I tried this solution but it is the same.

Comment: Impossible @AbdollahSobhy. There must be something you aren't telling us. see the online demo.

Comment: I tried this solution of you:-

select * 
from vf_device_os 
where ltrim([name]) = '4.2(Jelly Bean)'

But with no result.
Sorry if I bothered you. If there is any information I can provide kindly, ask me. I already provided all data I know in the question.

Comment: then it's impossible to diagnosis. give us sample data.

Comment: scsimon, I tried the online solution and you are right. the result there is as expected. But on my machine using sql server management studio. There is no result. May be this information may help

Answer (score 0):

There are *two* spaces in there

```
'4.2  (Jelly Bean)'
```

Adding a separator to make it clear :

```
'4.2 | (Jelly Bean)'
```

Given this table :

```
declare @device_os table ([id] [smallint] NOT NULL,[name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL)

INSERT @device_os ([id], [name]) 
VALUES 
(114, N'4.4.2'),
(115, N'2.3.64.14.14.1'),
(116, N'6.1.5'),
(117, N'4.0.0'),
(118, N'4.4.2 KOT49H.H1'),
(119, N'unknown'),
(120, N'CrunKeD! Galaxy Ace Ventura'),
(121, N'7.0.5'),
(122, N'7.0.6'),
(123, N'6.1.6'),
(124, N'4.4.2 (0Din Edition)'),
(132, N'7.1.1'),
(133, N'OS'),
(134, N'4.2  (Jelly Bean)'),
(135, N'5.0.0.1036'),
(136, N'7.1.0.285'),
(137, N'6.0.0.756'),
(138, N'ICS Powered By PMP Engine'),
(139, N'6.0.0.668')
```

The original query won't return anything:

```
select * from @device_os
where name = '4.2 (Jelly Bean)'

id  name
--- -----------------
```

Using two spaces between `4.2` and `Jelly Bean` though will return the record:

```
select * from @device_os
where name = '4.2  (Jelly Bean)'

id  name
--- -----------------
134 4.2  (Jelly Bean)
```

Comment: I take the value from the table as copy paste.. I didn't type it manually. I did the following: - 
1- Run (SELECT *) query.
2- Take the value "4.2  (Jelly Bean)" as copy paste from the (select *) query. 3- Put it in the where condition of the second query. 
The result is the same.  No data returned  :(

Comment: @AbdollahSobhy did you try with *two* spaces? What you posted in the comment has only *one* space. The data in the answer is the data you provided in your script, and it *does* work with two spaces

Comment: yes friend I tried with two spaces and no result returned.
I also tried these:- 
1- select * from device_os where name like '%4.2  (Jelly Bean)%'
And also no result.
Only this format worked but it is useless to me:-
select * from device_os where name like '%4.2%(Jelly Bean)%'

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of the problem after much trials.
It looks like special characters were inserted when the data was initially inserted and it is not appear in the SSMS. I did the following:-

1. update this record in the database table:-

   ```
   update device_os set name='4.2 (Jelly Bean)' where id=134
   ```

2. Run the same select statement again:-

   ```
   select * 
   from device_os where 
   [name] = '4.2 (Jelly Bean)'
   ```

Now, it is working...

Thanks every body...